# Estrutura aninhada saindo da condição FOR - Python

Tags: python, django, loop

Preciso fazer uma consulta em duas tabelas diferentes, e salvar os dados de ambos em uma terceira tabela com os dados unificados.

Estou acessando as tabelas e salvado os dados na nova tabela, porém o código lê somente a primeira linha, quando ele acha a primeira linha com a condição IF, salva no banco e sai da condição, deixando de percorrer a tabela por completo.

O erro está no FOR, todo o restante do código está funcionando, porém não estou conseguindo montar a estrutura corrreta para o código funcionar conforme o esperado e preciso de ajuda para entender, ou uma sugestão melhor para realizar essa função.

```
cursor_tb1 = utils.connect_mdb_tabela_1().cursor()
cursor_tb2 = utils.connect_mdb_tabela_2().cursor()

cursor_tb_1.execute(
    'SELECT tb1_id, tb1_pi, tb1_re, tb1_dig, tb1_disparo, tb1_situacao, tb1_condicao, tb1_resultado FROM tb_pmrpv WHERE tb1_pi > ' + str(
        ultimo_cadastro) + ' AND tb1_pi IS NOT NULL ORDER BY tb1_id ASC')

cursor_tb_2.execute('SELECT tb2_RE, tb2_DIG, tb2_POSTO, tb2_NOME, tb2_SEXO, tb2_OPM, tb2_SITUA FROM tb_2 ORDER BY tb2_RE ASC')

for row_tb1 in cursor_tb1.fetchall():
    for row_tb2 in cursor_tb2.fetchall():
        if str(row_tb1.tb1_re) == str(row_tb2.tb2_RE):
            field_id = str(row_tb1.tb1_pi)
            field_re = str(row_tb1.tb1_re) + '-' + str(row_tb1.tb1_dig)
            field_disparo = str(row_tb1.tb1_disparo)
            field_servico = str(row_tb1.tb1_situacao)
            field_condicao = str(row_tb1.tb1_condicao)
            field_resultado = str(row_tb1.tb1_resultado)
            field_nome = str(row_tb2.tb2_NOME)
            field_posto = str(row_tb2.tb2_POSTO)
            field_opm = str(row_tb2.tb2_OPM)
            field_situacao = str(row_tb2.tb2_SITUA)
            field_sexo = str(row_tb2.tb2_SEXO)


            save_fields(field_id, field_re, field_disparo, field_servico, field_condicao, field_resultado,
                                field_nome, field_posto, field_opm, field_situacao, field_sexo)

cursor_tb_1.close()
cursor_tb_2.close()
```

Answer (score -2):

bom pelo que eu vi do código sua condição esta sendo verdadeira somente uma x erro deve estar nessa linha:
if str(row_tb1.tb1_re) == str(row_tb2.tb2_RE):

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).